# Java, Don't wait for a thread to complete

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to find a way to spin off a thread from a static call and not wait for the thread to complete.  Basically, a "fire and forget" approach.  Can someone supply me with a simple example of how this can be accomplished?

Comment: That's basically the default behavior of a thread - is this thread going to need to signal the dispatching thread at some point or change the state of a shared variable?  More detail would be nice.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
Thread t = new Thread(new YourClassThatImplementsRunnable());
t.start();

// JDK 8
new Thread(() -> methodYouWantToRun()).start();
```

Answer (score 11):

If it's a long-lived thread that has a similar lifecycle to your app itself, and is going to be spending a lot of its time waiting on other threads:

```
new Thread(new yourLongRunningProcessThatImplementsRunnable()).start();
```

If it's a short-lived, CPU-bound task:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.availableProcessors());
es.submit(new yourTaskThatImplementsRunnable());
```

Though, in most cases like this, you will be submitting a number of tasks to that same `ExecutorService`.

## See:

- [Java Concurrency Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)
- [ExecutorService](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)
- [ExecutorCompletionService](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html)
- [Runnable](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)
- [Thread](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)
- [Future](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

Answer (score 7):

```
public static void foo() {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
                     //do something here....
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: But if the task is relatively simple, use the Runnable constructor for Thread (that is, new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() { ... } })), since that way you're not extending a complicated class, but implementing an interface, which should be simpler in the bytecode and you won't have any name clashes with the methods in Thread.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the nature of your task, different ways may be approrpiate:

(1) As many have mentioned, a common way for an occasional task is simply to **construct a thread and call its start()** method.

(2) Remember that if your background thread doesn't stop, then by default it will prevent your program from shutting down when other threads have finished. You **may therefore want to call setDaemon(true) on the thread** so that it doesn't have this behaviour. (In GUI-based applications, on the other hand, you usually end up just calling System.exit() anyway, and ideally you'd buile into your long-running task a *clean* way of shutting down.)

(3) If you **frequently have short-lived tasks** to "fire and forget", then consider using the [Executors framework](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/ThreadPoolExecutor.shtml) available from Java 5 onwards.

Answer (score 2):

basically start the thread and dont perform join. So you will not be waiting for the thread to finish.